# Having ablution(wudu)

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Does "having ablution" mean "performing ablution" in some contexts ? When I say "she is having ablution" , would it be correct and in the meaning of to perform it??

Comment: What does wudu mean?

Comment: Where have you seen 'having ablution'?

Comment: [Wuḍūʾ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wudu) (Arabic: الوضوء‎ al-wuḍūʼ [wʊˈdˤuːʔ]) is the Islamic procedure for cleansing parts of the body, a type of ritual purification, or ablution. Wudu involves washing the hands, mouth, nostrils, arms, head and feet with water and is an important part of ritual purity in Islam.

Comment: In my opinion she could only be "having ablutions" if someone else was cleaning her, and even then it would be a very unusual use of the word. If she's ritually cleansing herself then she is "performing her ablutions" as Markus Hendriksen says in nis answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't typically say *having ablution* in English.  Rather we say:  *perform* [ablutions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ablution).

> She is performing her ablutions.

It is worth noting that while *ablution* is a word, the plural form is usually used in English -- ablutions.  The singular form is usually only used to describe the act itself.

> *She went to the well for her ablution*.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ablution Ablution (singular) is a word, This is why it's best to site sources.

Comment: Please see my edits.